# Hide some digit of user mobile no for security reason

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

if u what to show any user Mobile on your website but as per security reason you are not display full Mobile No like  9305070207 you only show 93*****207.
try this regex -:

```
 var str="9305070207";
        var str1="9305070207";
        var formetNum = str.replace(/\d{8}$/,'')+str1.replace(/^\d{7}/,'*****');
        document.write(formetNum);
```

if any better way of this process please tell me . i improve my knowledge

Comment: This looks a bit odd.  What is the problem you are encountering with your code?  What would a "better way" do differently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could get the first two numbers and replace all numbers until three character are left over.

It works for any length of a string.

```js
var string = '9305070207',
    replaced= string.slice(0, 2) + string.slice(2).replace(/.(?=...)/g, '*');

console.log(replaced);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var str="9305070207";
    var str1="9305070207";
    var formetNum = str.replace(/\d{8}$/,'')+str1.replace(/^\d{7}/,'*****');
    document.write(formetNum);
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: i'm sorry about short/incomplete question . i complete my question and answer thanks for your comment .

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex group(change 2 or 3 stand for how many digit show front and end):

```
const string = '9305070207'
const replaced= string.replace(/^(\d{2})\d+(\d{3})$/, '$1*****$2')
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex and replacement. It's much faster (since you want a "better" way) just to slice:

```js
let string = '9305070207'
let replaced = string.slice(0, 2) + "*".repeat(string.length - 5) + string.slice(-3)

console.log(replaced);
```

<sub>benchmarks if you're curious:</sub>

```js
// top answer
const r = str => str.slice(0, 2) + str.slice(2).replace(/.(?=...)/g, "*")
// slice method
const s = str => str.slice(0, 2) + "*".repeat(str.length - 5) + str.slice(-3)

const numbers = Array.from({ length: 1e6 }, () => Math.random().toString().slice(2, 12))

console.time("regex")
for(let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
  r(numbers[i])
console.timeEnd("regex")

console.time("slice")
for(let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
  s(numbers[i])
console.timeEnd("slice")
```